# no interleave in output while both parent and child are writing to stdout

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork, race-condition

I was trying to write code to see how to use fork to create child process. Since the child inherit the file object and descriptor from parent, if both child and parent write to the stdout, there should be interleave in the output if I understand correctly. In the following code I write, I declare two strings in both parent and child, and I write them to stdout. The thing I observe is there is no interleave in the output. Do I miss something?

The code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
  pid_t return_value;
  pid_t wait_p;
  if ((return_value = fork()) != 0) {
     char pa[15]= "Hi from parent\n";
     char pa_2[18]= "Hello from pariii\n";
     write(1, pa, 15);
     write(1, pa_2, 18);
  } else {
     char c[17] = "Hello from child\n";
     char c_2[14] = "Hi from chiii\n";
     write(1, c , 17);
     write(1, c_2, 14);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

The output on my machine (Ubutun 18.04, complie with gcc):

```
Hi from parent
Hello from pariii
Hello from child
Hi from chiii
```

---

I see how the atomic nature of write may lead the process to not interleave. But why the output appear as if the parent execute all write first then the child execute its write? Also, no matter how many times I tried, the parent always appear to write before the child write.

Comment: "interleave"? What kind of "interleave"?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm guessing something like `HHiello ffromro parm chilentd` in the output, which could happen if each character were written individually.

Comment: Both answers below are correct.  Unless your platform is quite primitive, you are unlikely to see anything more than line-level interleaving.  Change your output method to use something like putc() and forcing output with flush() _might_ induce what you are looking for, but no guarantees.

Comment: You might (or might not) get more interesting results if you were writing large quantities (megabytes, or at least multiple tens of kilobytes) of data in the strings (so the size specified to the write calls will be many kilobytes) and the output is going to a pipe or terminal, but with tiny strings like the ones shown, you'll not see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `write` system call is *atomic*; that is, it all happens at once. There isn't a chance for the strings to be interleaved. If you were to make the `write` call in multiple parts (for example, write the string `"Hi from "`, and then write the string `"parent"` or `"child"`, and then write a newline), then you will probably see interleaving. When you `write` the entire message as a single string, that will never happen.

Note that higher-level calls, like `printf` or similar, have more complicated buffering rules and therefore might have different rules.

---

In response to the added question about why the two parent lines are always before the two child lines, it isn't exactly luck but it isn't guaranteed. On the same system with the same settings, I would expect that it would be mostly consistent whether it scheduled the parent first or the child first, but other platforms might make the opposite decision.

As for why it never prints one line from the parent, then one line from the child, then the second line from the parent, I'd guess it has to do with the specifics of the scheduler and writing to a virtual terminal. Context switching from one process to another is expensive; if the `write` is fast enough the scheduler might be able to tell it shouldn't do that. Perhaps if you wrote to disc instead, and called `sync` in between `write`s to make sure the (relatively slow) disc was actually involved, it would be more likely to interleave. Or perhaps not; it's really hard to predict. If you really want to see interleaving, I'd write at least a handful of kilobytes, a few at a time, from both the parent and the child; that would be close to certain to interleave.

Answer (score 2):

> there should be interleave in the output

No, the output *may* be interlaced. Or it may not. It's up to the scheduler, or the phase of the moon.